# LIMIT_EXCEEDED, limit exceeded: [] when creating Community User

Tags: community, dmlexception, customer-community-plus

Suddenly getting the following error:

> System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first
> error: LIMIT_EXCEEDED, limit exceeded: []

when trying to insert a Community User via apex code. This is not happening in our DEV sandbox and only happening on a specific Account record. This Account is related to the Contact record created for the Community User. Any help is appreciated.

[image]

[image]

Comment: i am getting the same error.
Can you kindly give me some more details on the change you made to solve "Partner Role restricts access to this Account"? Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Figured out why. The Account associated to the Contact was owned by someone else and the Partner Role restricts access to this Account. I can successfully create the Community User for this Account now. Thanks!